# PHP - Convert an escaped character into hex

Tags: php

Having trouble finding a way to convert an escaped character within a string to its hexadecimal value.

For example:

```
$tab = "\t";
$hexTab = escapedToHex($tab);
echo $hexTab; // prints "09"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User ord to get the ascii value and then dechex to convert to hex

```
dechex(ord($tab));
```